# Simple string concatenation fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-concatenation, yahoo-finance, nonetype

I have the following code:

```
from yahoo_finance import Currency

symbolslist  = ["EURUSD","EURGBP","EURJPY","EURRUB","USDCAD","USDCHF","AUSUSD"]

for i in range(len(symbolslist)):
        symbol = symbolslist[i]
        nomisma = Currency(symbol).get_rate()

        quota = symbol + " = " + nomisma
        print quota
```

And I get the result:

```
EURUSD = 1.0891
EURGBP = 0.7322
EURJPY = 129.7440
EURRUB = 63.0560
USDCAD = 1.2614
USDCHF = 0.9622
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yahoopy.py", line 13, in <module>
    quota = symbol + " = " + nomisma
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

I'm aware that this error has been talked about in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064233/python-cannot-concatenate-str-and-nonetype-objects) link.

But I was hoping that I could overcome this bug without resorting to mysql.

Comment: How can that be? The program fetches data straight from the Yahoo Finance website via the yahoo_finance API. It's weird that it crashes at the last value AUDUSD.

Comment: just an OT advise: you can loop through your array by its elements with "for symbol in symbolslist"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is a typo. Instead of `AUDUSD` you wrote `AUSUSD`. Fix it and the error will be gone:

```
symbolslist  = ["EURUSD","EURGBP","EURJPY","EURRUB","USDCAD","USDCHF","AUDUSD"]
```

Still it is a good idea to use `format` as @BhargavRao suggested to catch such bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `if` clause above your concat statement

```
if nomisma:
    quota = symbol + " = " + nomisma
```

Assumption - It means that `AUSUSD` is not present in your database, that is why `Currency(symbol).get_rate()` is returning `None`. Also as mentioned [here](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AUDUSD=X) it is `AUDUSD` and not `AUSUSD`

Note : It is better to use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) to concat as in

```
quota = "{} = {}".format(symbol,nomisma)
```

Comment: You were right. It was my stupid typo that blew things apart. It works just fine now. Thanks for noticing it. I thought I had corrected that before...